# Detect login timeout in DNN on an AJAX request

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-5

We have a custom module that is being used on multiple pages in our DNN application. One of them is accessible to registered users only. The rest can be accessed anonymously. The main module control renders content using jQuery and AJAX. Requests are sent to a GetData.aspx on the server. We would like to handle the situation where user login has timed out due to inactivity. What happens currently is that even though the login has timed out, the user is able to click on a button in the module which sends a request to GetData.aspx, but here we are unable to detect whether user login has timed out. There might not always be a login, because some instances of the module are available anonymously as well. So checking `UserID=-1` does not help.
We have tried using:

```
 1. DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.ModulePermissionController.HasModuleAccess        
 2. DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.TabPermissionController.CanViewPage
```

Both always return "true" irrespective of the timeout or the UserId. DNN strongly advises against using ASP.Net Session. 
Is there a way in DNN to detect timeouts from within a module in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

In out application we have followed that create HTTPModule using IHTTPHandler, so that we can check the every request and we findout the timeout of particular request.